# Function implementation is missing or not immediately following the declaration, TypeScript class

Tags: angular, function, typescript, class, declaration

I got a handwritten array to fill a table in my class, now I'm getting this array's 
 content from a JSON on ngOnInit but it's not structured as I need.

So I'm trying to write a function to fill the table array with this new one I'm getting on ngOnInit.

The issue is that when I write code outside of a function in my TS class I get this error "Function implementation is missing or not immediately following the declaration".

Why is that and what can be done to fix this?

TS

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
    users: Object;

    constructor(private tstService: MyComponentService) { this.source = new LocalDataSource(this.data) }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.tstService.getTstWithObservable()
        .map(result => result.map(i => i.user.data))
        .subscribe(
           res => { this.users = res; }
       );
    }

    console.log(this.users); // Here, just an example. Throws 'Function implementation is missing or not immediately following the declaration'

    data = [
        {
          title: 'Monthly',
          sdate: '01/04/1990',
          edate: '30/09/1990',
        },
      ];

    source: LocalDataSource;
}
```

Comment: Thought the explanation was enough. Just edited the OP. The issue is that anything that I write outside of a function or ngOnInit throws the mentioned error.

Comment: Try declaring your variables before your constructor (data & source).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The issue here is that you have some "code execution" (`console.log(this.users);`) outside an "executable area" (for instance the "area" inside the `ngOnInit`).

If you need to do `console.log(this.users);` in order to see the data in the devtools, you should move the `console.log` part inside the `ngOnInit` which is an executable part of you class `MyComponent` or maybe inside the `constructor`.

I would recommend you to do it like this:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.tstService.getTstWithObservable()
    .map(result => result.map(i => i.user.data))
    .subscribe(
       res => {
                this.users = res;
                console.log(this.users); // <-- moved here!
       }
   );
}
```

The thing is the code you're trying to execute needs to be inside some method which Angular executes.

See [**this demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kxzwge?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts) with some examples. The relevant code is below:

```
export class AppComponent  implements OnInit{
  name = 'Angular 6';

  constructor() {
    console.log(name); // OK
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('sample not giving error'); // OK
  }

 // comment line below and the error will go away
  console.log(name); // this will throw: Function implementation is missing or not immediately following the declaration
}
```

Comment: Just realized this! Thanks for the explanation