# How to Print Values in console Without passing in any Function?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I just want to print something in console in my typescript file. But whenever I tried to do the same , it gives a error.

```
console.log(this.dataList);
```

**Error:**

> error TS2391: Function implementation is missing or not immediately following the declaration.

Comment: You are writing the console.log in the class definition.

Comment: Move it inside a method.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the console log in init function or in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

A calss can contain only functions and declarations. Not definitions. try putting the log in any of the methods or constructor

[Function implementation is missing or not immediately following the declaration, TypeScript class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51266438/function-implementation-is-missing-or-not-immediately-following-the-declaration)