# How to pass optional parameters while omitting some other optional parameters without using undefined and empty ("")

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I need to call the function with omitting some optional parameter without using undefined and "".

```
import { MouseEvent } from "react";
import { DialogType } from "editor-constants";

export interface DialogOptions {
  className?: string;
}

export class Dialog {
  id: string;
  type: DialogType;
  title?: string;
  message?: string;
  onOk?: DialogHandler;
  onCancel?: DialogHandler;
  options?: DialogOptions;
  cancelButton?: string;
  okButton?: string;

constructor(
  id: string,
  type: DialogType,
  title = "",
  message = "",
  onOk?: DialogHandler,
  onCancel?: DialogHandler,
  cancelButton?: string,
  okButton?: string
) {
    this.id = id;
    this.type = type;
    this.title = title;
    this.message = message;
    this.onOk = onOk;
    this.onCancel = onCancel;
    this.cancelButton = cancelButton;
    this.okButton     = okButton;
  }
 }

 export type DialogHandler = (e: MouseEvent) => void;
```

I need to call this function Like:

```
 openConfirmDialog(title, message, onOk, "", "", cancelButton, okButton);
```

without using empty ..I should call... can anyone help.

Comment: In this case you can define constructor like this : constructor({
  id: string,
  type: DialogType,
  title = "",
  message = "",
  onOk?: DialogHandler,
  onCancel?: DialogHandler,
  cancelButton?: string,
  okButton?: string
})

Comment: Im asking i have to call( openConfirmDialog(title, message, onOk, "", "", cancelButton, okButton); ) the function without using "" and undefined

Answer (score 0):

You can change your function to accept an object as argument :

```
constructor({
  id: string,
  type: DialogType,
  title = "",
  message = "",
  onOk?: DialogHandler,
  onCancel?: DialogHandler,
  cancelButton?: string,
  okButton?: string
})
```

And then call the function, and pass the non-empty data in the object, the rest of the keys in the function's argument object will take the default value.

```
openConfirmDialog({title, message, onOk, cancelButton, okButton});
```

Comment: its throwing error like constructor implementation is missing

Comment: type DialogHandler = (e: MouseEvent<Element, globalThis.MouseEvent>) => void
Constructor implementation is missing.ts(2390) Like this in editor ....                                                                And parsing error: ',' expected in cmd

Comment: I think this is more related to how your code is structured and executed. Maybe this will help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51266438/function-implementation-is-missing-or-not-immediately-following-the-declaration/51267574